# How to use an EditText as an indicator

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to use an EditText as an indicator to show values, which i receive from a remote device. So the text in the EditText must not be editable. How to do that ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it sounds like you're trying to use it for, a [`TextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) would be more appropriate, as others have suggested.

However, if you're set on using an EditText for a particular reason, you can achieve what you're looking for by disabling the EditText.  This greys it out and prevents the user from editing the text.  You can do this either statically (in XML) or dynamically (in Java).

XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:text="This is disabled." />
```

Java:

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editText1.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) isntead. That is what TextView is for. If you read its documentation it says: `It displays text to the user and optionally allows them to edit it. A TextView is a complete text editor, however the basic class is configured to not allow editing`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `TextView`. Set any text you want. It is un-editable.

TextView myTextView;

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
   ....
   myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

   myTextView.setText("Hello world");
}
```

For further info [**LINK**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html).